# Hover over effect pushing image down

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

Here is an image of the `media div` with the `on hover X` I have:

[image]

Here is an image of when you click on the div and upload a photo. As you can see it fits nicely inside the box.

[image]

Finally here is a div when I `hover over` the image to see the `X`.

[image]

As you can see the image got pushed down. **My end result is instead to have it hover over the image and not affect the images placement**

Here's my CSS:

```
.x {
  color:red;
  #width:50px;
  #height:50px;
  display:none;
  #left:50px;
}
.MediaPreview:hover > .x {
  display:block;
}
.MediaPreview {
    position: absolute;
    width: 128px;
    height: 72px;
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    cursor: default;
}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="MediaPreview" style="left: 10px; bottom: 10px;">
  <span>Image or video, required</span>
   <div class="x">x</div>
</div>
```

Comment: does my answer correct on your question ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
.x {
  color:red;
  #width:50px;
  #height:50px;
  display:none;

  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;

}
.MediaPreview:hover > .x {
  display:block;
}
.MediaPreview {
    position: absolute;
    width: 128px;
    height: 72px;
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    cursor: default;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply `position:absolute` to `.x`, not `.MediaPreview`. Try this:

```
.x {
  color:red;
  display:none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.MediaPreview:hover > .x {
  display:block;
}
.MediaPreview {
    position: relative;
    width: 128px;
    height: 72px;
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    cursor: default;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how to get the job done. Using pure css

```
<div class="mediapreview">

<a href="#" class="upsize red">X</a>

<img src="http://hub.n2growth.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/About-People-2.jpg" alt="people" class="responsive">

</div>
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/brceg73x/1/)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:
https://jsfiddle.net/maky/gqn1nrxj/

```
.x {
  color:red;
  display:none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.MediaPreview:hover > .x {
  display:block;
}
.MediaPreview {
    position: relative;
    padding:10px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    cursor: default;
}
```